# Cannot remove a diagnostic setting with Remove-AzDiagnosticSetting

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-diagnostics

I have an diagnostic setting on Database/Master and I am having some difficulty with deleting it in AzureCLI.

So I use

`Remove-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId "/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/PainfulRG/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/testsqltoday/databases/db1" -Name Jason`

and it comes back with a Status of OK.

I then look at the activity log within the diagnostic settings within Azure Portal and I see :

```
  "resourceId": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/PainfulRG/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/testsqltoday/databases/db1/providers/Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/Jason",
    "status": {
        "value": "Succeeded",
        "localizedValue": "Succeeded"
    },
    "subStatus": {
        "value": "OK",
        "localizedValue": "OK (HTTP Status Code: 200)"
    },
```

So it seems it was OK (200 status).

But when I go to the diagnostic settings and click on db1 - and then into diagnostic settings - the setting is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below rest API to delete diagnostic settings

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/diagnostic-settings/delete

Comment: Wondering why the Az powershell `Remove-AzDiagnosticSetting` doesn't supports this.